# Getting more than one index from item in list

Tags: python

This is the code that I have got to get one item in the list:

```
LetterInput = 'A'

LetterPositions = (DisplayWord.index(LetterInput))
```

The DisplayWord is from a external file (that is made into a list) that looks like this:

```
ACQUIRED

ALMANAC

INSULT

JOKE

HYMN

GAZELLE

AMAZON 

EYEBROWS

AFFIX

VELLUM
```

I want to change it so all of the position `A` is, is saved into a list as there are more than one position the `A` can be.

Comment: so you want the position for every `A` in every word? So a list of lists?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find all position of `LetterInput` in `DisplayWord`:

```
LetterPositions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(LetterInput, DisplayWord)]
```

For example:

```
>>> LetterInput = 'A'
>>> DisplayWord = 'ALMANAC'
>>> LetterPositions = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(LetterInput, DisplayWord)]
>>> LetterPositions
[0, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def positions(letter,input_letter):
...     return [ i for i,x in enumerate(letter) if input_letter == x  ]
... 
>>> positions('ALMANAC','A')
[0, 3, 5]
```

if input_letter equals it gives i, that is position of 'A'